# How should a test be written for a delegate for editing?

Tags: testing, model-view-controller, qt5, pyqt5

I have a tree view for which some fields need to use a custom delegate for editing.  The delegate presents a `QListView` for value selection.  It seems like the `QAbstractItemView.edit()` method should be used to initiate the edit from the test but I can't figure out how to get access to the created editor (a `QListView`) so I can select the proper element for the test.

This is part of a test I had working with a `QComboBox` delegate before switching to the `QListVew`, but it seems too manual.

```py
for index, enumerator in enumerate(group.children):
    editor = delegate.createEditor(
        parent=viewport,
        option=None,
        index=target_index,
    )

    editor.setCurrentIndex(index)
    delegate.setModelData(editor, model, target_index)
    assert enumerator.uuid == item.enumeration_uuid
```

https://github.com/altendky/st/commit/643c5c30f87fc3bfd8b422687e81f740ec36ef44#diff-06bc81dbbd9f7a12878169d5238e1572R846

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.

https://github.com/altendky/st/blob/089432162b9e8ca67eafdfcc2a4ecc34e8f0e96e/epyqlib/tests/test_attrsmodel.py#L848

```py
for row, enumerator in enumerate(group.children):
    assert view.edit(
        target_index,
        PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers,
        None,
    )
    editor, = view.findChildren(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QListView)

    index = editor.model().index(row, 0, editor.rootIndex())
    editor.setCurrentIndex(index)
    editor.clicked.emit(index)

    # this is fun.  if you get weird issues try doing this more times
    for _ in range(3):
        application.processEvents()

    assert enumerator.uuid == item.enumeration_uuid
```

Do note that I connect the editor's clicked signal to post an enter-key event since the view's are hardcoded to catch an enter event and finish editing.